# JDev 12 and Java EE CDI

Tags: cdi, jdeveloper

I'm trying to use Java EE CDI in an ADF app in JDev 12.2.1, but even with this simple case:

```
public class ClassA { }

public class ClassB {
    @Inject ClassA injected;
}
```

It appears to create two copies of the ClassA bean and fails with an Ambiguous dependencies error. Has anyone else got CDI working in JDev 12.2.1? Is there a project or weblogic setting that I've got wrong?

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type ClassA with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassB.injected
  at ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassB.injected(ClassB.java:0)
  Possible dependencies:
  - Managed Bean [class ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassA] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassA] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type ClassA with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassB.injected
  at ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassB.injected(ClassB.java:0)
  Possible dependencies:
  - Managed Bean [class ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassA] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.ClassA] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

                at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
                at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
                at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
                at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
                at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
                Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Looks like your class is present 2 times on the classpath, check it.

Comment: This was actually a bug in JDev 12.2.1...moving to a newer version resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Class ClassA has a default scope and it is [@Dependent](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html). This bean will be created at the point of injection. Look where the bean of class ClassA will be created and injected. Destruction of the bean with scope @Dependent depend of instance of class where it will be injected. If you have not this point, so create it, or change the scope of this bean. for exemple put @ApplicationScope and check it.